# React-native without open keyboard of TextInput, Paste text to TextInput on android and ios

Tags: react-native

*I want to paste text to TextInput but when focus input, i dont want open keyboard.*

i used

> showSoftInputOnFocus={false}

```
 <TextInput
      showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      style={styles.InputStyle}
    />
```

- on android i cant paste anything even keyboard not open. However on ios it still opens.
  How can i handle this senerio ? or is there  suggestion for better way  for this senerio ?*

Comment: showSoftInputOnFocus is an Android only property so it shouldn't have any effect in iOS. As an alternate approach, you could keep a read-only text field with a past button that takes the current clipboard values and sets it manually into the state.

Comment: @nipuna777 thank you for answer. And almost it helps, however i used editable={false} for ios but  when text so long, i cant see all text for check. because of  i cant focus textInput